# How to calculate business days between two dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, module, packet

I need to calculate business days (excluding holidays) between two dates. How can I do it?

I tried to do it manually but I need to keep all the holidays in one place. I do not want to do this. I am using my sql as a database.

Comment: Hello @erdemhho you can use moment which is a famous date library in js ecosystem or if you want to go something lightweight then you can use dayjs or date-fns

Comment: @Bhumit070 I don't think momentjs keeps a "holidays" calendar. And even if it did, it's probably outdated by now, because momentjs is considered deprecated by its authors for quite a while and doesn't receive any updates anymore ...

Comment: First of all, you would need to specify, the country/countries you want to support, because holidays are different in each country. There may be libraries supporting this for various countries. But in the end it really comes down to iterate over all days between your two dates and check for each day, if it is a weekend/holiday or not.